# New line and tab characters in python on mac

Tags: python, macos, newline

I am printing a string to the python shell on a mac os 10.7.3.

The string contains new line characters, \n\r, and tabs, \t.

I'm not 100% sure what new line characters are used on each platform, however i've tried every combination (\n, \n\r, \r) and the newline characters are printed on the shell:

```
 'hello\n\r\tworld'
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you outputting this string?

Comment: i'm just doing, print myString

Comment: What happens when you do `print repr(myString)`?  Do the `'\n'` look like `'\\n'`?

Comment: if they look like \\n that means those are not special characters (tabs, newline, etc.) but rather a regular \ char followed by a letter char (t, n, etc.). originally they may have been tabs and newlines though.

Comment: Any ideas on how i can resolve this issue ? many thanks

Answer (score 2):

What look to you like newlines and carriage returns are actually two characters each -- a back slash plus a normal character.

Fix this by using `your_string.decode('string_escape')`:

```
>>> s = 'hello\\n\\r\\tworld'   # or s = r'hello\n\r\tworld'
>>> print s
hello\n\r\tworld
>>> print repr(s)
'hello\\n\\r\\tworld'
>>> print s.decode('string_escape')
hello
        world
```