# How to write to a new line every time in python?

Tags: python, io

I'm just trying to append new tweets that come in to a new line
in a file.... So far nothing i'm trying works on OS X Python.

```
  class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
      def on_status(self, status):
          print status.text

          with open("myNewFile", "a") as file:
          file.write('\n')
          file.write("\n" + status.text + "\n")
          file.write('\n')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What actually happens?

Comment: this is whats in the file.../n#LOQOOTV send stuff to public TVs, just bying using hashtags/n#LOQOOTV wonder can use chromcast??/n#LOQOOTV secrecy/n#LOQOOTV testttt/n#LOQOOTV testttttttt/n#LOQOOTV public TV network!

Comment: You have forward slashes in your actual code, don't you.

Comment: yes, I'm using the code examples from below. verbatim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an issue with indentation:

```
  with open("myNewFile", "a") as file:
  file.write('\n')
  file.write("\n" + status.text + "\n")
  file.write('\n')
```

If you want to be inside the `with` context, you should indent the following three lines to the right.

Further, you can use `format()` to prepare the string you want to write, for efficiency and readibility:

```
  import os
  with open("myNewFile", "a") as file:
      file.write('{0}{0} {1} {0}{0}'.format(os.linesep, status.text)
      #file.write('\n')
      #file.write("\n" + status.text + "\n")
      #file.write('\n')
```

Note the `os.linesep` to insert an OS independent new line :).

You can also write two `linesep` by repeating them twice (multiply the string by 2):

```
file.write('{0} {1} {0}'.format(os.linesep * 2, status.text)
```

Which is cleaner.

Comment: your top answer almost qualifies for the populist gold badge, just voted it up, good luck :)

Comment: I tried this too... and no new lines! everything just keeps getting added to a continuous line in the file. what gives??

Comment: @sirvonandrethomas Edited my answer to suggest using `os.linsep`. Are you on windows?

Comment: @VioncenzoPii no I'm on OSX ML

Comment: @sirvonandrethomas, did you try `linesep`? I'm curious now!

Comment: Yup, I've tried every code example so far and it repeats the same behavior. All data keeps added to a continous line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34282/discussion-between-sirvon-andre-thomas-and-vincenzo-pii)

Comment: Not restarting a script :)

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong in your `with` staement

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
  def on_status(self, status):
    print status.text

    with open("myNewFile", "a") as file:
      file.write('\n')                           #move this over 1 indentation
      file.write("\n" + status.text + "\n")      #move this over 1 indentation
      file.write('\n')                           #move this over 1 indentation
```

Also try `'\r\n'` instead of just `'\n'` because UNIX handles newlines differently than windows.

Another option is to open the file with [universal newline support](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) like this

```
    with open("myNewFile", "u") as file:
```

Note that "u" mode is deprecated in 3.x since it is default

**edit 2**
It seems that your newline characters are showing up in the output.  See  [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420337/new-line-and-tab-characters-in-python-on-mac)

Comment: +1, Nice one, I didn't know about the `"u"` option, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/

Comment: Universal newlines are for reading. You can't open a file for writing in universal newlines mode.

Comment: neither did i.  Found it on another stackoverflow  answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax:

```
print >>file, status.text
```

This does the same as the normal `print` function except it outputs to the file (so it will put a newline at the end, just like the normal `print`)

Comment: nope, i tried it. It just adds it to the end of it's last addition. dunno what gives.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the updated code? This and the answer from @Vincenzo Pii both look like they should work.

Comment: its the same code verbatim.... and this is what i get ... /n#LOQOOTV send stuff to public TVs, just bying using hashtags/n#LOQOOTV wonder can use chromcast??/n#LOQOOTV secrecy/n#LOQOOTV testttt

Comment: those are the tweets being added to the file

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on, but the slashes should be backslashes (\) for the newline escape

Comment: im not putting those in there, that's just whats coming out as a result of your code...

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
entry = '\n' + status.text

f = open('myNewFile', 'a')
f.write(entry)
f.close()
```

Comment: I am saving a list of tuples [(a,b,c),(x,y,z),(p,q,r)]. How to save this to text file with each tuple on a new line?